# Launch an add-in systematically when opening a file

Tags: excel, office-js

I want to make an Excel Online file, then post its link or embed it in my website. Clicking on that will open the file in Excel Online. Moreover, I want certain Excel add-ins to be installed and even launched automatically.

Does anyone know if it is possible?

If it's impossible with Excel Online, is it possible for a normal `.xlsx` file (I will make it, and opening it in Windows systematically leads to install an add-in and even launch it)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking to automatically open a task pane add-in when the Excel file is opened, check out this article in the documentation: https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/design/automatically-open-a-task-pane-with-a-document?product=excel. The [Office OOXML EmbedAddin](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-OOXML-EmbedAddin) sample provides an example of implementing the *autoopen* functionality that's described in the article.

Comment: Could you confirm if it is possible to enable autoopen of a task pane in a document in OneDrive (i.e. when users view this document in Excel Online, the task pane will be automatically opened)?

Answer (score 1):

Along with Kim's answer to automatic opening of a task pane add-in, you can using OneDrive to handle opening a file in Excel Online using [Microsoft Graph](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/).

You're start by uploading you're `.xlsx` file to OneDrive using an [Upload Session](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/driveitem_createuploadsession). Once you're file is on OneDrive, you can retrieve it's meta-data for the [DriveItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/driveitem_get). Included in this meta-data will be a `webUrl` property. This is a URL that, when navigated too, will open your file using Excel Online.

Comment: When we open an Excel file in OneDrive, we could click on `Share` on the top right, then `Get a link`, is it the same link as `webUrl` you described?

Comment: Could you confirm if it is possible to enable autoopen of a task pane in a document in OneDrive (i.e. when users view this document in Excel Online, the task pane will be automatically opened)?